# Why guard doesn't protect root route, only children?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a routing module that contains 3 routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SystemComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'vds-list', component: VdsListComponent},
      {path: 'phone-list', component: PhonesListComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SystemRoutingModule {
}
```

But `AuthGuard` protects only the child routes, `vds-list` and `phone-list`. That's a problem because I need to protect the root route `/`, too.

**UPDATE 1** `AuthGuard`

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
        queryParams: {
          accessDenied: true
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.canActivate(childRoute, state);
  }
}
```

And `AuthService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private loggedIn = false;

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  login(user: User) {
    this.loggedIn = true;
    window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.router.navigate(['/vds-list']);
  }

  logout() {
    this.loggedIn = false;
    window.localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `AuthGuard` code routing to if authentication fails?

Comment: @Narm oh! My mistake. Update question.

Comment: You are also missing the route `login` from your routes...

Comment: @Alex yes it causes all auth routes lie in auth-route.module. Auth is the independent module.

Comment: @Pavel Ah see, I didn't notice this wasn't app-routing module, so ignore my comment :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your AuthGuard. It needs both CanActivate-method for the parent and CanActivateChild-method for its children.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      let url: string = state.url;

      return this.check(url);
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry I thought the only router.module important for this process. Now I add my  AuthGuard in question. In my version method canAvtivate() implemented but root not protected. Maybe I don't right understand your answer. AuthGurd doesn't call when I move to root URL.

Comment: I'd recommend you to read this article. It's covers this topic quit well:  https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-route-guards-canactivate-and-canactivatechild-example -- hope this helps.