# Guard on children routes

Tags: angular, typescript, guard

I know the subject has often been treated on StackOverflow.

I consulted several posts on Stack but the suggested solution doesn't work for me.

For exemple [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493883/why-guard-doesnt-protect-root-route-only-children)

I try for the first time to restrict access to pages by using Guards but it doesn't  work for child pages.

I have a Truck module containing childs like that :

```
Truck
  |_ truck-list
  |_ truck-search
  |_ truck-menu
  |_ truck-details
```

I have a route file for the Truck module :

```js
RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: 'list', component: TruckListComponent, canActivate: [TruckGuard]},
    {path: 'search', component: TruckSearchComponent, canActivate: [TruckGuard]},
    {path: 'details/:id', component: TruckDetailsComponent},
    {path: 'menu', component: TruckMenuListComponent},
    {path: 'menu/:id', component: TruckMenuListComponent},
    {path: 'menu/add/:id', component: TruckMenuAddComponent},
    ])
```

and an app-routing module :

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'app-forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent},
    { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'About', component: AboutComponent},
    { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent},
    { path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'Logout', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'confirmation-commande/:message', component: ConfirmationCommandeComponent},
    { path: 'orders', component: OrderListComponent},
    { path: 'truck/search', component: TruckSearchComponent},
    { path: 'SignUp/customer', component: UseraccountCreateCustomerComponent},
    { path: 'SignUp/truck', component: UseraccountCreateTruckComponent},
    { path: 'useraccount', loadChildren: () => import('./useraccount/useraccount.module').then(u => u.UserAccountModule)},
    { path: 'truck', loadChildren: () => import('./truck/truck.module').then(t => t.TruckModule)},
    {path: 'location', component: TruckLocationComponent},
    { path: '500', component: InternalServerComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ];
...
```

I also created a Truck.guard.ts file to manage route for the truck module :

```js
export class TruckGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private route: Router) {}
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url = window.location.pathname;

    if((url == '/truck') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      this.route.navigate(['app-forbidden']);
      return false;
    }
  }
 
  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url = window.location.pathname;

    if((url == '/truck/list') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else if((url == '/truck/search') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else if((url == '/Login') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      this.route.navigate(['app-forbidden']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The only path that works is `truck/list`. He is well redirected to forbbiden page.

All the others doesn't work.

I don't understand why. Howver I use canActivate and canActivateChild.

Thanks in advence for your help.

Comment: You will also need to add a `canActivateChild` property to the routes. The respective function in the guard will only be invoked if the route is specifying that explicit function. See https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly the solution is to add canActivateChild in the app-module.ts:

```js
 { path: 'truck', loadChildren: () => import('./truck/truck.module').then(t => t.TruckModule), canActivateChild: [TruckGuard]},
```

and test url in the guard file using  `state: RouterStateSnapshot` in place of `window.location.pathname` like this :

```js
 if((state.url == '/truck/list') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else if((state.url == '/truck/search') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
   else if((state.url == '/truck/menu') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else if((state.url == '/truck/menu/' + childRoute.params['id']) && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else if((state.url == '/truck/details/' + childRoute.params['id']) && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else if((state.url == '/Login') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      this.route.navigate(['app-forbidden']);
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a couple of things wrong.

1. The reason truck/list works is because you are applying canActivate on it and not the rest here

   ```
    {path: 'list', component: TruckListComponent, canActivate: [TruckGuard]},
   ```

and in your canActivate you are only catering for truck/list here

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
let url = window.location.pathname;

if((url == '/truck') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
  return true;
}
else{
  this.route.navigate(['app-forbidden']);
  return false;
}
```

}

2. The reason why others are not working is because you are not applying canActivateChild to the parent module.

add a canActivateChild to the appRoute like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'app-forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent},
{ path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'About', component: AboutComponent},
{ path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent},
{ path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'Logout', component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'confirmation-commande/:message', component: ConfirmationCommandeComponent},
{ path: 'orders', component: OrderListComponent},
{ path: 'truck/search', component: TruckSearchComponent},
{ path: 'SignUp/customer', component: UseraccountCreateCustomerComponent},
{ path: 'SignUp/truck', component: UseraccountCreateTruckComponent},
{ path: 'useraccount', loadChildren: () => 
import('./useraccount/useraccount.module').then(u => u.UserAccountModule)},
// Truck module Your canActivateChild comes here    
{ path: 'truck', loadChildren: () => import('./truck/truck.module').then(t=> t.TruckModule)}, canActivateChild:TruckGuard // <<< HERE
{path: 'location', component: TruckLocationComponent},
{ path: '500', component: InternalServerComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

];

Comment: Ok it seems to be better but how to test url with parameter? ex: ` else if((url == '/truck/menu/:id') && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }`
This does not work.

Comment: Ok I have the answer to my question. I have to use this to test params : `else if((url == '/truck/menu/' + childRoute.params['id']) && this.authService.isCustomer()){
      return true;
    }`

Comment: Another problem is that on one page I have a button to redirect to another page but when I test url in my Guard page it's the current url not the asked url.

Comment: @Paintbox have you fixed your second issue? Also i would suggest you use a switch statement in place of all this if/else